# Showing Probability Inequalities

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I have to show the following inequality, given that $X$ is a non-negative random variable with Var$(X)\leq \frac{1}{2}$
$$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}(X)-1\leq X\leq 2\mathbb{E}(X))\geq \frac{1}{2}.$$

So far, I've tried splitting the probability as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}(X)-1\leq X\leq 2\mathbb{E}(X))=\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2\mathbb{E}(X))-\mathbb{P}(X<\mathbb{E}(X)-1)$$

Which, since $\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2\mathbb{E}(X))=1-\mathbb{P}(X> 2\mathbb{E}(X))$, I can use Markov's inequality to bound this below by $\frac{1}{2}$.

Alternatively, $\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2\mathbb{E}(X))=\mathbb{P}(0\leq X\leq 2\mathbb{E}(X))=\mathbb{P}(|X-E(X)|\leq \mathbb{E}(X))$ since $X$ is non-negative. I can use (either a corollary of Markov's or Chebychev's inequality) to bound this below by $1-\frac{1}{2\mathbb{E}(X)^2}$ using the same trick.

In either case, I cannot seem to get anything meaningful out of the latter term, as I'm left with the probability I'm trying to estimate being bounded below by $\frac{1}{2}-\mathbb{P}(X<\mathbb{E}(X)-1)$ or $1-\frac{1}{2\mathbb{E}(X)^2}-\mathbb{P}(X<\mathbb{E}(X)-1)$.

Comment: Try bounding the second term above by something. Use the fact that $P(X \leq E[X]-1) = P(2X \leq 2E[X]-2) = P(|2X-E[X]+1| \leq E[X]-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu\in (1,\infty)$, $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(\mu -1 \leq X \leq 2\mu ) & \geq &\mathbb{P}\big(|X-\mu|\leq 1\big) \\ & \geq & \mathbb{P}\big(|X-\mu|<1\big) \\ &=& 1- \mathbb{P}\big(|X-\mu|\geq 1\big) \\ &=&1- \mathbb{P}\big((X-\mu)^2\geq 1^2\big) \\ &\geq& 1- \frac{\mathbb{E}\Big[(X-\mu)^2\Big]}{1^2} \\ &=& 1- \text{Var}(X) \\ &\geq & \frac{1}{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$ Now if $\mu \in (0,1],$ $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(\mu-1\leq X \leq 2\mu) &=& \mathbb{P}(X \leq 2\mu) \\ & \geq & \mathbb{P}(X<2\mu) \\ &=& 1- \mathbb{P}(X \geq 2\mu) \\ &\geq & 1- \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{2\mu} \\ &=& \frac{1}{2} \end{eqnarray*}$$ Evidently $\mathbb{P}(X>0)=0$ if $\mu=0$. To see this, take any $\epsilon>0$. We get $$\mathbb{P}(X\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{\epsilon}=\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}=0$$ So $\mathbb{P}(X>0)=0$ since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary making $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1$.